Sveltekit form action not receiving updated reactive variable
I have a variable like this
let subject = writable({
    name: '',
    students: []
});

And a form
<form class="subject-form" method="POST" action="?/create"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="subject" value={subject} />
    <!-- ... (other stuff) -->

     {#each $subject.students as student, index}
          <label for="student-name-{index}">Nombre:</label>
          <input
               id="student-name-{index}"
               type="text"
               bind:value={alumno.nombre}
               required
          />
     {/each}
</form>

On the server side I have an action to make a request to some BE
export const actions = {
    create: async ({ cookies, request }) => {
        const data = await request.formData();

But the request received here does not have any of the data of the subject variable. It's just empty, like an empty string.

You cannot send entire objects like that, and subject would be the store, not the store content. Also, in case you expected anything to be on data.subject on the server: FormData has a method-based API for reading data; values are read via get() or getAll(), so here it would be data.get('subject').
You can either flatten the object into many fields that are sent separately or e.g. use JSON.stringify($subject) to send everything JSON-encoded as one field (this would need to be decoded again on the server).
If you intended to send multiple fields: The input in the #each does not have a name, so nothing is sent.
